# Positioning an element with CSS

Tags: css, css-position

Oh, that awkward moment when I feel I have no clue how CSS works...

I am trying to layout a Kanban board in CSS. A board contains columns which in turn contain tasks. Schematically, it's as simple as:

[image]

where a board is a div, a column is a div, and a task is a div with some paragraphs.

I am trying to make the columns full-height, and this is where I am getting a problem — for some reason the columns containing tasks get pushed all the way towards the bottom of the page (while columns without tasks don't).

Here is a CodePen link with an example of this behavior: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbOBrj.

(and the css code, since SO insists that links to codepan have to be accompanied by code):

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

#app{
  height: 100%;
}

.board{
  background: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.column{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  background: gray;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.task{
  background: yellow;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Could you please suggest how to correct this? Preferably, without using floats.

(If you could also explain why this is happening, that would make me so happy. I am very much puzzled by this behavior.)

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, the link you provided gives both the answer and a detailed explanation.

Comment: @showdev: do I need to remove this question (if so, how?) or can it stay?

Comment: *(and the css code, since SO insists that links to codepan have to be accompanied by code)* ... only because links don't always last, and if the question relies solely on the link, then it loses it's value when the link dies..

Comment: @azangru No, it can stay. I find your question useful. For more information, see [Should I delete my question if it is marked as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on how `inline-blocks` are aligned and then add `vertical-align:top;` to your `.column` class to fix your problem

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmWgjG

Comment: Thank you! I actually thought of vertical-align and tried it, but I think I applied it to the parent div. When applied to `.column`, it works perfectly. Thank you!